# The intersection of all stabilizers in a continuous action

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group (locally compact and Hausdorff) continuously acting on a topological space $M$. Does this implies that the normal subgroup of $G$ made by the elements fixing each $m\in M$ is closed? 
If so, any hint on how to prove it?

Comment: $G\times M\to M$ is continuous

Comment: @Max Yep, that's the definition. But an hint on how to use it? I'm not used to topological arguments unfortunately.

Comment: This is not enough, but imagine if sequences were enough : if $g_n\to g$ as $n\to\infty$ and $m\in M$, then $g_nm\to gm$ but also $g_nm= m$ (I was very vague in my quantification but it's on purpose)

Comment: Ok, I probably understand that I need something more, something like all points of M are closed.

Answer (score 2):

We could use nets to see it (often handy in topological group arguments, I find):

so the action $a: G \times X \to X$ where $a(g,x) = g \cdot x$ is a continuous map.

Let $I \to g_i$ be a net in $G$ in the said normal subgroup, and suppose $g_i \to g$.

Let $x \in X$, then $g \cdot x = a(g,x) = a(\lim_i g_i, x) = \lim_i a(g_i,x)$ (by continuity of $a$ in the first coordinate) $= \lim_i g_i \cdot x = \lim_i x = x$ as each $g_i$ fixes $x$. As $x \in X$ is arbitrary, so $g$ is also in the intersection of all stabilisers. So that set is closed under net-limits, hence closed.

No assumptions on $G$ are needed, and we use Hausdorffness on $X$ because we want the limits of nets to be uniquely defined. Eric Wofsey points out in his answer that something on $X$ is needed here..

Comment: This only works assuming $X$ is Hausdorff, so that $\lim_i x$ is uniquely defined.  Or, I guess, $T_1$ would be enough.

Comment: But your argument relies on the assumption that two different limits of this net must be equal.  That just won't work in general (and in fact the result is not true in general).

Answer (score 1):

This is false in general.  For instance, if $M$ has the indiscrete topology, then any action of $G$ on $M$ is continuous, so the normal subgroup fixing all elements of $M$ could be any normal subgroup at all (given any normal subgroup $N$, let $M=G/N$ with the usual action).

It is true assuming $M$ is $T_1$.  Indeed, in that case the subgroup in question is just the intersection of the closed sets $\mu_m^{-1}(\{m\})$ for each $m\in M$, where $\mu_m:G\to M$ is the map $\mu_m(g)=g\cdot m$.